# Invalid argument "/tensorflow-serving-devel" for "-t,--tag" flag:Invalid reference format

Tags: git, docker, tensorflow, git-clone, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to create a docker Image for tensforflow serving like [here](https://github.com/llSourcell/How-to-Deploy-a-Tensorflow-Model-in-Production/blob/master/demo.ipynb).

When i try to pull docker image with all the required dependencies(pip dependencies, bazel, grpc)
[image]

What am i doing wrong here? I believe it works for everyone except me.
i am using docker toolbox in windows 7 and this is my first time using docker. I don't know what this error says

edit: after removing the space
[image]

Docker version

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a typo in your `docker build` command: a space is after `Dockerfile` word.

The correct command is:

```
docker build --pull -t $USER/tensorflow-serving-devel -f tensorflow_serving/tools/docker/Dockerfile.devel .
```

EDIT:

I see where your problem is. You use Windows, so `$USER` is not resolves to username. Please change it to something else like:

```
docker build --pull -t user/tensorflow-serving-devel -f tensorflow_serving/tools/docker/Dockerfile.devel .
```

And then use it with `docker run` command:

```
docker run --name=tensorflow_container -it user/tensorflow-serving-devel
```

Comment: Docker version 18.02.0 -ce, build

Comment: @dhinar Added additional info.

Comment: I have added a pic above,is that enough

Comment: @dhinar Please read my answer one more time. I added additional info there.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `$USER` is expanding to an empty string, since there is no environment variable `USER`.

To solve the issue just replace the `$USER` with your Dockerhub username or any username. You can also just change `$USER/tensorflow-serving-devel` to `tensorflow-serving-devel`. It really doesn't matter
since this is only the name of the resulting image.

Comment: Had same issue, one of my variables was not being expanded. Going to debug that now, haha

Answer (score 1):

In my case with the same error, the problem was with combination of "**-**" and "**_**" symbols placed together in the image tag. So image tag like `MMT-6352_-_fix` is invalid, but image tag like `MMT-6352_fix` or `MMT-6352-fix` is valid.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am creating an environment variable with hash of recent git commit, and this hash value will be the tag of my docker image I'm going to build.

So my file(say `deploy.sh`) looked like this:

```
GIT_SHA = $(git rev-parse HEAD)
docker build -t user/myimage:$GIT_SHA
```

Then, I got error saying

```
deploy.sh: line 2: GIT_SHA: command not found
invalid argument "user/myimage:" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format
See 'docker build --help'.
```

I fixed it by removing the spaces before and after `=` as follows:

```
GIT_SHA=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
docker build -t user/myimage:$GIT_SHA
```